# Bootstrap and Css image logo not displaying central on Device

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I have the following html contact us non descript template from bootstrap that is centering the logo fine on my laptop but on my Iphone it is displaying to the right and i have to scroll across.

```
<div class="aboutus-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="aboutus">
                        <h2 class="aboutus-title">About Us</h2>
                        <p class="aboutus-text">Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in.</p>
                        <p class="aboutus-text">This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem</p>
                        <a class="aboutus-more" href="#">read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="aboutus-banner">
                        <img style="-webkit-user-select: none;margin: auto;background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 80%);transition: 
                        background-color 270ms;" src="images/logo_full.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="feature">
                        <div class="feature-box">
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <div class="iconset">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="feature-content">
                                    <h4>Work with heart</h4>
                                    <p>Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="feature-box">
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <div class="iconset">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="feature-content">
                                    <h4>Reliable services</h4>
                                    <p>Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibu. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="feature-box">
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <div class="iconset">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog icon"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="feature-content">
                                    <h4>Great support</h4>
                                    <p>Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the outcome on laptop:

[laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIpso.png)
This is the outcome on iphone:
[iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYm78.jpg)

Comment: I think you need to use css media query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.aboutus-banner{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

You can use flexbox for this as given above or there is bootstrap class as d-flex justify-content-center